# Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcalendar"

Tags: vcalendar

I am trying to generate a vCalendar but i am getting an error "response is not available in this context"

on   Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcalendar" .

I am using vb.net , 1.1 framework.

Any ideas?

-MIthil

Comment: We need some context. For example, where is this code being called?

Comment: I got it working. I added the reponse on a totally new aspx page.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your code is wrapped up in a class you may not be able to access the Response.  You could try using HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType.